# Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push') TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, react-router

I have this react component where I display students from a database and every student has 3 actions butons. The thing is that pressing the view button gets me this error:

```
ERROR
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')
(other stuff)
```

This is the component that I use:

```
import { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import HeaderComponent from './HeaderComponent';
// Services import
import StudentService from '../services/StudentService'; // Import the service that provides student data
import AdminOfficeService from '../services/AdminOfficeService';

class ListStudentComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            students: [], // Initialize students state
        };
        // Bind de los métodos
        this.addStudent = this.addStudent.bind(this);
        this.viewStudent = this.viewStudent.bind(this);
        this.updateStudent = this.updateStudent.bind(this);
        this.deleteStudent = this.deleteStudent.bind(this);
    }

    static propTypes = {
        history: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    };

    addStudent() {
        // Add a student
        this.props.history.push('/create');
    }

    viewStudent(rut) {
        // Navigate to the student details page
        console.log(this.props);
        this.props.history.push(`/${rut}`);
        console.log(this.props);
    }

    refreshTable() {
        // Fetch updated student data and update the state
        StudentService.getAllStudents().then((res) => {
            this.setState({ students: res.data });
        });
    }

    updateStudent(rut) {
        // Get student by id and update
        AdminOfficeService.updateStudentInfo(rut).then(() => {
            // After updating, refresh the table
            this.refreshTable();
        });
    }

    deleteStudent(rut) {
        // Delete a student
        StudentService.deleteStudent(rut).then(() => {
            // After deleting, refresh the table
            this.refreshTable();
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        StudentService.getAllStudents().then((res) => {
            // Fetch student data when the component mounts
            this.setState({ students: res.data });
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <StudentPageStyle>
                    <HeaderComponent />
                    <h2 className="table-name">Students List</h2>
                    <div className="row">
                        <table className="student-table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th> Student RUT</th>
                                    <th> School name</th>
                                    <th> Exams taken</th>
                                    <th> Average score</th>
                                    <th className="buttons"> Actions</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                {this.state.students.map(
                                    // Map over the students state to create a table row for each student
                                    (student) => (
                                        <tr key={student.rut}>
                                            <td> {student.rut} </td>
                                            <td> {student.schoolName}</td>
                                            <td> {student.examsTaken}</td>
                                            <td> {student.averageScore}</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <button
                                                    onClick={() =>
                                                        this.viewStudent(
                                                            student.rut
                                                        )
                                                    }
                                                    className="btn btn-info"
                                                >
                                                    View
                                                </button>
                                                <button
                                                    style={{
                                                        marginLeft: '10px',
                                                    }}
                                                    onClick={() =>
                                                        this.updateStudent(
                                                            student.rut
                                                        )
                                                    }
                                                    className="btn btn-info"
                                                >
                                                    Update
                                                </button>
                                                <button
                                                    style={{
                                                        marginLeft: '10px',
                                                    }}
                                                    onClick={() =>
                                                        this.deleteStudent(
                                                            student.rut
                                                        )
                                                    }
                                                    className="btn btn-danger"
                                                >
                                                    Delete
                                                </button>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    )
                                )}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </StudentPageStyle>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ListStudentComponent;
```

and this is the app.js

```
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
// Home component
import HomeComponent from './components/HomeComponent';
// Student components
import StudentListComponent from './components/StudentListComponent';
import StudentDetailsComponent from './components/StudentDetailsComponent';
import CreateStudentComponent from './components/CreateStudentComponent';

function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Router>
                <Routes>
                    {/* Home page */}
                    <Route path="/" element={<HomeComponent />} />
                    {/* Student list */}
                    <Route
                        path="/students"
                        element={<StudentListComponent />}
                    />
                    {/* Student details */}
                    <Route
                        path="/students/:rut"
                        element={<StudentDetailsComponent />}
                    />
                    {/* Create student */}
                    <Route
                        path="/create"
                        element={<CreateStudentComponent />}
                    />
                </Routes>
            </Router>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Can someone help me?

I tried to define the props.history but this is my first time into react and I´m not sure what to do